# Why is the shader editor stuck on 1 material?

Tags: modeling, shaders

I have been working on a car model but just now I found that the body material is still stuck in the shader editor when I was working on something else. The selection drop-down menu is completely greyed out and I can't do anything to fix it. I tried exporting the FBX file and saving it as .blend but nothing worked. Can anyone please help? Here is a photo for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push pin button is enabled on the Shader Editor View.  This locks the view.

[       ]

Please disable the the push pin to allow the view to synchronize with the current object selected. ⛸

Comment: Why a link to manual is a bad thing? Also the button/icon is a "pin" (pinning) and the shader editor is not a *view* rather an *area*...

Comment: You're welcome... Downvoted regardless, reasons in first comment.